# De Excel a archivo CSV a diccionarios dentro de una lista

Tags: python, lista, csv

Tengo este código que trae un archivo excel que fue convertido a ARCHIVO CSV:

```
import csv

with open("SERVICIO DE AGUA CSV.csv") as archivo_csv:
    archivo = csv.reader(archivo_csv, delimiter=",")
    contador_linea = 0
    for fila in archivo:
        if contador_linea == 0:
            print("Las columnas son ", fila[0], fila[1], fila[2])
        else:
            print(fila[0])
            print(" Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana", fila[1])
            print(" NO tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana", fila[2])
        contador_linea += 1
    print("Lineas procesadas: ", contador_linea)
```

Que me imprime esto:

```
    Las columnas son  Departamento Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana No tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana
     Amazonas
 Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    60 437
 NO tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    18 934
 Áncash
 Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    218 655
 NO tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    27 995
 Apurímac
 Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    95 096
 NO tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    12 818
 Arequipa
 Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    295 356
 NO tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana    43 526
```

Quiero un codigo que me imprima esta lista que dentro de ellas los diccionarios:

```
Agua=[{'Departamento': 'Amazonas',  'Sí tiene servicio de agua': '60 437','NO tiene servicio de aguav': '18 934' }, {'Departamento': 'Ancash',  'Sí tiene servicio de agua': '218 655','NO tiene servicio de aguav': ' 27 995' }, {'Departamento': ' Apurímac',  'Sí tiene servicio de agua': '95 096','NO tiene servicio de aguav': '12 818' }, {'Departamento': 'Arequipa',  'Sí tiene servicio de agua': '295 356','NO tiene servicio de aguav': '43 526' }]
```

Implemente este código pero no me sale nada o me sale en desorden:

```
 reader = csv.DictReader(archivo_csv)  
    for row in reader:
        lista.append(row)
```

Comment: Hola. ¿En qué orden quieres que salgan los diccionarios?

Comment: Hola, como el código que puse quiero que me imprima así. :) gracias

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias. Acabo de publicar una respuesta con código para imprimir la lista como has mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el archivo "SERVICIO DE AGUA CSV.csv" la coma (`,`) como **separador** y este contenido:

```
"Departamento","Sí tiene servicio de agua","NO tiene servicio de agua"
"Amazonas","60 437","18 934"
"Ancash","218 655","27 995"
"Apurímac","95 096","12 818"
"Arequipa","295 356","43 526"
```

Podemos definir la siguiente función para obtener una representación como `string` de una lista de diccionarios:

```py
def get_list_str(l):
    result = "Agua=["
    list_size = len(l)

    for i, d in enumerate(l):
        result += "{"
        d_size = len(d)

        for j, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
            result += f"'{k}': '{v}'"

            if j < d_size - 1:
                result += ","

        result += "}"

        if i < list_size - 1:
            result += ","

    result += "]"
    
    return result
```

Y el siguiente código:

```py
lista = []

with open("SERVICIO DE AGUA CSV.csv") as archivo_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(archivo_csv, delimiter=",")

    for row in reader:
        lista.append(row)

print(f"Agua={lista}")
```

imprime lo siguiente:

```
Agua=[{'Departamento': 'Amazonas','Sí tiene servicio de agua': '60 437','NO tiene servicio de agua': '18 934'},{'Departamento': 'Ancash','Sí tiene servicio de agua': '218 655','NO tiene servicio de agua': '27 995'},{'Departamento': 'Apurímac','Sí tiene servicio de agua': '95 096','NO tiene servicio de agua': '12 818'},{'Departamento': 'Arequipa','Sí tiene servicio de agua': '295 356','NO tiene servicio de agua': '43 526'}]
```

Comment: Hola, añadí ese código y me sale esto: Traceback (most recent call last):
error en : for row in reader:
  line 111, in __next__self.fieldnames
  line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
 line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 14: invalid continuation byte

Comment: y si pongo el codigo sin:  encoding="utf-8" me sale: Agua=[OrderedDict([('Departamento', ' Amazonas'), ('Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana', '   60 437'),('No tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana', '   18 934')])

Comment: y al cambiar mi archivo UTF-8: Agua=[OrderedDict([('\ufeffDepartamento', ' Amazonas'), ('Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana', '   60 437'), ('No tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana', '   18 934')]), OrderedDict([('\ufeffDepartamento', ' Áncash'), ('Sí tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana', '   218 655'), ('No tiene servicio de agua todos los días de la semana', '   27 995')]),

Comment: Hola. Entonces es que tu archivo CSV no tiene codificación UTF-8, por lo que puedes quitar la parte de "encoding="utf-8"". Acabo de modificar mi respuesta, mira si ahora te sirve.